# Black screen after importing .ova in Virtual Box?

Tags: debian, kali-linux, virtualbox

Hello I've got a problem. I have downloaded the Kali Linux Image (.ova) for Virtual Box, but when I start it and click on "Kali GNU / Linux" there is a black screen.

**Extra Information:**

Im on **Windows 10**
Im using this Image: **Kali Linux VirtualBox 64-Bit (OVA) version 2020.4**
Virtualbox version: **6.1**

**Screenshots:**
[image: Grub]
[image: Kali GNU / Linux]
[image: Loading...]
[image: Black Screen]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community! Please add some more information about your setup. What is your host OS, what software versions are you running, which version of the OVA did you download and so on.

Comment: @Thorian93 I just edited my question

Comment: Have you tried resizing the window? That is a long shot, but I have seen some interesting effect with VBox.

Comment: Please add details about your VBox-version, too.